# Slow debugging in .NET Core

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

We are developing a web application in ASP.NET Core (1.1.2), and we are experiencing a huge slowness in debugging. We are using Visual Studio 2015, but i'm guessing that it has more to do with .NET Core than with Visual Studio. But I might be wrong. Is this a known issue with .NET Core at the moment? Will upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 help in some way? And are there any known workarounds for this? The whole team is having the same problem, so it can't be just my specific machine that's problematic.

Thanks,
ashilon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that as a workaround, there might be a solution that might work:
Go to Tools | Options | Debugging | General and check "Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators" option.
Worked for me, might work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 won't help you.

Just try to deactivate the diagnostic tool in Visual Studio and see the result:

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General (Then, uncheck "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging")

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help Harold. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any affect on the slowness of the debugging.